# How to display element hidden by "*" in html

Tags: html, jave

i have a problem with my account. hacker took my account. he changed my email address, fortunately my phone number still remains, I used my phone number to get my account back, but he changed my username too. I don't know that username right now because it's covered by the "*" signs. Can you help me to display these characters? thank you very much ! love u
[This is the picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55yRl.png)]

Comment: This an excellent question to ask the support of the platform. No question that you should ask at SO. The recovery of a hacked user account is not a coding question.

Comment: hello Quốc Nguyễn Hữu. I am so sorry to here that. Perhaps this article can help you https://consumer.ftc.gov/articles/how-recover-your-hacked-email-or-social-media-account

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If the element is already showing with stars on the HTML, there are a few chances that the page contains your full username. Replacing with stars is a common technique to prevent hacker from getting people's username. So, there are few chances that you get your username back with that.